# How to access Mbeans values from my JConsole?

Tags: java, jmx

I have written a JMX code to expose the values in the program. I can see these values in JConsole.

How can I access these values from another program so as to show these values in UI format?

Answer (score 0):

Please see jolokia framework(http://www.jolokia.org/), it is remote JMX with JSON over HTTP.It's very easy using.

Comment: I am getting same reply always. My application does not run on a application server. It is a standalone JVM. Can you give an example how to use jolokia?

Comment: Check out the [JVM agent](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html#agents-jvm), this works for *any* Java process.